# Jetpack Compose LazyColumn inside Scrollabe Column

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

here's my situation: I have to show in my app a detail of a record I receive from API. Inside this view, I may or may not need to show some data coming from another viewmodel, based on a field.

Here my code:

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun ViewDetail(viewModel: MainViewModel, alias: String?, otherViewModel: OtherViewModel) {
    viewModel.get(alias)

    Scaffold {
        val isLoading by viewModel.isLoading.collectAsState()
        val details by viewModel.details.collectAsState()

        when {
            isLoading -> LoadingUi()
            else -> Details(details, otherViewModel)
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
private fun Details(details: Foo?, otherViewModel: OtherViewModel) {
    details?.let { sh ->
        val scrollState = rememberScrollState()

        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .verticalScroll(scrollState),
        ) {
            Text(sh.title, fontSize = 24.sp, lineHeight = 30.sp)

            Text(text = sh.description)

            if (sh.other.isNotEmpty()) {
                otherViewModel.load(sh.other)
                val others by otherViewModel.list.collectAsState()

                Others(others)
            }
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
private fun Others(others: Flow<PagingData<Other>>) {
    val items: LazyPagingItems<Other> = others.collectAsLazyPagingItems()

    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .wrapContentHeight(),
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(16.dp),
    ) {
        items(items = items) { item ->
            if (item != null) {
                Text(text = item.title, fontSize = 24.sp)

                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(4.dp))

                Text(text = item.description)
            }
        }

        if (items.itemCount == 0) {
            item { EmptyContent() }
        }
    }
}
```

All the description here may be very long, both on the main Details body or in the Others (when present), so here's why the scroll behaviour requested.

Problem: I get this error:

```
Vertically scrollable component was measured with an infinity maximum height constraints, which is disallowed. One of the common reasons is nesting layouts like LazyColumn and Column(Modifier.verticalScroll()).
```

I hoped that `.wrapContentHeight()` inside LazyColumn would do the trick, but to no avail.

Is this the right way to do it?

Context: all packages are updated to the latest versions available on maven

Comment: You're already checking `items.itemCount` during `LazyColumn` build, why don't you add your column content into lazy column using the same principles?

Comment: @PylypDukhov I dont understand your point

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The main idea here is to merge your `Column` with `LazyColumn`.

As your code is not runnable, I'm giving more a pseudo code, which should theoretically work.

Also calling `otherViewModel.load(sh.other)` directly from Composable builder is a mistake. According to [thinking in compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/mental-model), to get best performance your view should be side effects free. To solve this issue Compose have special [side effect functions](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects). Right now your code is gonna be called on each recomposition.

```kotlin
if (sh.other.isNotEmpty()) {
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        otherViewModel.load(sh.other)
    }
}
val others by otherViewModel.list.collectAsState()

LazyColumn(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .wrapContentHeight(),
    contentPadding = PaddingValues(16.dp),
) {
    item {
        Text(sh.title, fontSize = 24.sp, lineHeight = 30.sp)

        Text(text = sh.description)
    }
    
    items(items = items) { item ->
        if (item != null) {
            Text(text = item.title, fontSize = 24.sp)

            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(4.dp))

            Text(text = item.description)
        }
    }

    if (items.itemCount == 0) {
        item { EmptyContent() }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a system like the following

```
@Composable
fun Test() {
    Box(Modifier.systemBarsPadding()) {
        Details()
    }
}

@Composable
fun Details() {
    LazyColumn(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        item {
            Box(Modifier.background(Color.Cyan).padding(16.dp)) {
                Text(text = "Hello World!")
            }
        }
        item {
            Box(Modifier.background(Color.Yellow).padding(16.dp)) {
                Text(text = "Another data")
            }
        }
        item {
            Others()
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Others() {
    val values = MutableList(50) { it }

    values.forEach {
        Box(
            Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(16.dp)
        ) {
            Text(text = "Value = $it")
        }
    }
}
```

The result with scroll is:

[image: This is the result]

Comment: I like your idea to use Item as content, but enters in a infinite loop

Comment: This approach is equivalent to using regular Column. All the data within `item {}` is loaded at once. So this can't be used for long or infinite lists.