# LazyColumn inside LazyColumn

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn

I am trying to create and list with sub list using `LazyColumn` with the code below

```
DropdownMenu(
    expanded = expandedDomain,
    onDismissRequest = { expandedDomain = false },
) {
    LazyColumn {
        items(1) {
            Checkbox(checked = false /*checkedState.value*/,
                onCheckedChange = {})
            Text(text = "$domainResponse.domains[0].name")
        }
        LazyColumn {
            items(domainResponse.domains[0].pwas) { pwas ->
                Checkbox(checked = false /*checkedState.value*/,
                    onCheckedChange = {})
                Text(text = "$pwas")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Error:**

```
@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function
```

Comment: did you check following link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63801346/composable-invocations-can-only-happen-from-the-context-of-an-composable-funct

Comment: @YodgorbekKomilov I am not calling any composable from onClick

Comment: If you look at the constructor argument its not a `@Compose` function - `content: (@ExtensionFunctionType LazyListScope.() -> Unit`.  Within the `LazyListScope` you can call other functions that accept `@Composable` functions.  Just use `items { .. }` twice inside one `LazyColumn`.

Comment: An example of multiple items inside one `LazyColumn` can be seeing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71884867/3585796)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me try to explain in parts what you should be changing.

#### 1. Why did the error occur?

> `@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function` occurred

If we peek into `LazyColumn` code, we can find `content: LazyListScope.() -> Unit` as the content parameter datatype.

This shows that the context does not have composable context.

On contrary, composables like `Column`/`Row` would have `content: @Composable ColumnScope.() -> Unit`/`content: @Composable RowScope.() -> Unit` respectively.

The `@Composable` shows that the `content` has a Composable context.

#### 2. How to fix it?

From what I see in the code, you don't need a `LazyColumn` inside another `LazyColumn`. You would need one `LazyColumn` with multiple items in it from different data sources.

You can change your code like this,

```
LazyColumn {
    item {
        Checkbox(checked = false /*checkedState.value*/,
            onCheckedChange = {})
        Text(text = "$domainResponse.domains[0].name")
    }
    items(domainResponse.domains[0].pwas) { pwas ->
        Checkbox(checked = false /*checkedState.value*/,
            onCheckedChange = {})
        Text(text = "$pwas")
    }
    // You can have multiple lists in a single LazyColumn
    items(list2Items) { item ->
        Text(text = "$item")
    }
}
```

#### 3. `item` vs `items`

Use `item` instead of `items(1)` if you have a single item as they are equivalent, but this would be more clear.

**P.S:**
`LazyColumn` uses `item` or `items` which have `itemContent` with composable context. Hence we can add Composables inside them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I still have one question that I need list of lazy column inside there will be another lazy list. How can I achieve it?

Comment: Can you post a video of what you are trying to achieve? A single `LazyColumn` can show data from multiple lists.

Comment: thanks Abhimanyu, would you please see this questin https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72044939/kotlin-flow-out-generic