# Kotlin Flow out generic

Tags: kotlin, generics, kotlin-flow

I am using `flow{}` builder to call the api and then `emit()` the response to `ViewModel`. I add return type of flow as `Flow<Resource<List<RemoteData>>>`. However, at some places in emit(), the Android Studio throws

```
error : Not enough information to infer type variable T
```

Because the `emit(Resource.Error(message = "Couldn't reach server, check your internet connection."))` is expecting values of type `List<RemoteData>` Please see my `Resource` class below

```
sealed class Resource<T>(val data: T? = null, val message: String? = null) {
    class Loading<T>(data: T? = null): Resource<T>(data)
    class Success<T>(data: T?): Resource<T>(data)
    class Error<T>(message: String, data: T? = null): Resource<T>(data, message)
}
```

My question, Is it safe to change emit to

```
emit(Resource.Error(
            message = "Couldn't reach server, check your internet connection.",
            data = null
        ))
```

And flow's return type as `Flow<Resource<out List<RemoteData>>>` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kotlin has declaration site variance. I would put `out` at the Resource class declaration. Then when you declare your type `Flow<Resource<List<RemoteData>>>`, it will already be implicitly `out List<RemoteData>`.

Also, your Resource classes look convoluted to me. If `data` is the loaded resource, it should not be part of the Loading or Error classes. Why force every instance of Loading and Error to carry a meaningless null `data` value? Likewise, the `message` should not be part of the Loading and Success cases.

I would rewrite your sealed class as a sealed interface (since it has no shared state between types) like this, and take advantage of data class features as well. `Loading` can be an `object` because it doesn't need to hold state. Loading and Error can both be `Resource<Nothing>` since the type `T` is irrelevant to any specific instance of them. That way you won't have to needlessly specify types when using them, like having to put `<RemoteData>` after `is Resource` or `is Error` in a `when` statement.

```
sealed interface Resource<out T> {
    object Loading: Resource<Nothing>
    data class Success<out T>(val data: T): Resource<T>
    data class Error(val message: String): Resource<Nothing>
}
```

This version of the sealed classes will be much easier to use. The compiler will be more lenient with how and where you need to specify generic types.

Comment: How can I reach to data from binding adapter cause it's available only when success state